# Token mismatch when using Trait RegistersUsers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

in my Laravel App to register my users im using the trait "RegistersUsers", and in my controller im overwritting a methdo available that i can use after a user is created, in my case after i user is created i need to create a record with the data previous passed to a table of billing_users.

The method used is:

```
/**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {

        // create record for the billing information
        $billing_employer = new BillingEmployer();
        $billing_employer->employer_id = $user->id;
        $billing_employer->country_id =  $user->country;
        $billing_employer->region_id =  $user->region;
        $billing_employer->registered_name =  $user->brand;
        $billing_employer->address =  $user->address;
        $billing_employer->save();

       return $billing_employer;
    }
```

The only problem is after running this method is giving me a error:
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

I had idea that Laravel already handle the token since before creating the record of user already passed this parameter.

Note:
For better understanding to do:
Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php and go to use RegistersUsers where is available the method example -> "protected function registered(Request $request, $user)"

What should i do?

Comment: Are you sending the `CSRF` along with this request? I assume you're doing this through AJAX? If so, you have to configure ajax to send the CSRF header

Comment: no, im not using ajax, im using a normal form post, and also the token is along the request.

Comment: did you include the CSRF token in the form?

Comment: Please include the form blade file

Comment: For better understanding please go to Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php and go to use RegistersUsers where is available the method example "protected function registered(Request $request, $user)"

Comment: beneath the `<form>` have you added `{{ csrf_field() }}`?